# Cannot include files from /usr/local/include even though they are present

Tags: xcode, compilation, include, xcode4.6.3

I'm not able to compile a project under Xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503) when using files located in `/usr/local`. The error is `'cryptopp/cryptlib.h' file not found`. This is similar to a number of other questions, but the 'try this'  mentioned in the other topics have not helped.

I have a directory with headers in them. The directory is `/usr/local/ios-armv7/include`. Within that directory the headers are located in `cryptopp/`. I am including the files with both `#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>` and `#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"`.

[image: header files on disk]

In Xcode, I have `/usr/local/ios-armv7/include` and `/usr/local/ios-armv7/include/cryptopp` set in every place that will take a path for headers or include files. There are no target overrides. I verified the paths are being added to the command line through `-I` switches.

[image: Xcode search paths]

I've tried toggling `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS`. I've tried toggling recursive. I've also tried adding and removing the trailing slash (`/`). In between each attempts, I perform a full clean. I also used Organizer to remove all data. I even tried using a different compiler (GCC-4.2, which appears completely broken).

What is the trick to get Xcode to honor my search path?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tracked this problem down to permissions on `usr/local/ios-arm7`. The permissions were 0600. I'm not sure how/why Finder was able to view them since I did not have permission. After `chmod -R 0644 usr/local/ios-arm7`, everything worked as expected. I could also remove all the extra paths I threw at the project.

Answer (score 3):

Wow...What a pain. I just figured it out (was fighting this same issue for some time).

It looks like there are two sets of settings, one for the project, and one for the target.

Look to the left of your build settings pane. If you have the project highlighted, hit the 'targets' icon, and then you'll see there is another set of build settings. As soon as I added '/usr/local/include' to my 'Header Search Paths' section, it found the external headers.

Comment: Jonas - sounds like you were providing target specific overrides. You can delete them on the target by highlighting the override and then hitting CMD+DELETE. Hint: the overrides are in bold font, the non-overrides are standard font. Once you delete the override, it goes back to standard font.